# Icon font inside input text issue (when I write a big word, the text starts to appear behind my icon)

Tags: html, css

I have an input text for search.

Inside this input have an icon font that is the submit button.

But I'm having a problem, if I write a text/word very big in my search input, the text when it comes closer to my button (icon font) it starts to get behind this button, as you can see in my image.

Do you know how I can fix this?

[image]

I have here my issue code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/zb39cr5f/

My HTML:

```
<li id="search" >
    <form id="search" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button type="submit" name="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <input name="s" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
    </form>
</li>
```

My CSS:

```
*{background:#ccc;}

#search
{
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
    height:20px; 
    bottom:2px;


}


#search button[type="submit"] 
{
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 15px;

}

button[type="submit"]>i:hover
{     
    color: #fff;

}   

button[type="submit"]>i
{
    background:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.1em; 

}


#search input[type="text"] 
{
    color:#fff;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size:14px;
    background: red;
    text-indent: 0;
    width:110px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

### DEMO:http://jsbin.com/menej/1/edit

Use box-sizing:border-box so it doesn't hit:

```
#search button[type="submit"] {
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 15px;
    border: 0px;
}

button[type="submit"]>i:hover {
    color: #fff
}

button[type="submit"]>i {
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#search input[type="text"],
#search input[type="search"] {
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: red;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 175px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 45px 8px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly! I just accept other answer because it was also correct and it was first! I hope you dontt mind. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, mine was first you can see it in the time stamp.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me! As the other answer appears first I forgot to confirm time.

Comment: Strange because most don't answer with the same answer.